# Extjs - How use Ext.util.Observable to get all form objects event click?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an application with multiple windows as customers, products and so on.
For each window I have several components as gridpanel, combo, button and so on.
My application has a timeout of 15 minutes, this way, if the user is inactive for 15 minutes, the application is closed.

So how could I do to get all click events of all objects
that interact with the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a controller and init it like so:

```
init: function (app) {
    this.control({
        'component': {
            click:function() {
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I may not have understood right your idea! Then, for each controller I must add this code snippet that you mentioned?

Comment: You create a new controller (not ViewController!) with only that function. A controller binds itself to everything in the whole app that matches the given selector, and since `component` is the base xtype of every component, every click event of every component should fire the function, which is empty at the moment. Inside that function you would have to add your business logic (resetting a timer or something like this).